# How to validate the authenticity of docker base images?

Tags: security, docker, checksum

How we can make sure that the docker base image for example ubuntu:latest are not corrupted?? That is how to check the authenticity of docker base images??

Comment: See also [How to pin public root key when downloading an image with docker pull (Docker Content Trust)?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/238916/how-to-pin-public-root-key-when-downloading-an-image-with-docker-pull-docker-co)

Comment: Are you worried about checking for corruption (integrity) or authenticity? They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

#### Checksum verification

`docker pull` verifies download of its each layer using Checksum. It will detect corrupted download.

```
$ docker pull ubuntu:latest 
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
1be7f2b886e8: Downloading [=====>                                             ]  4.865MB/42.86MB
6fbc4a21b806: Download complete 
c71a6f8e1378: Download complete 
4be3072e5a37: Verifying Checksum  <<-- It verifies Checksum 
06c6d2f59700: Download complete
```

So, you do not need to check where your pulled image is corrupted or not

#### Content trust in Docker

Content trust provides the ability to use digital signatures for data sent to and received from remote Docker registries. These signatures allow client-side verification of the integrity and publisher of specific image tags.

When you enable content trust, signing occurs on the client after push and verification happens on the client after pull

```
$ export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1; docker pull ubuntu:latest

Pull (1 of 1): ubuntu:latest@sha256:e27e9d7f7f28d67aa9e2d7540bdc2b33254b452ee8e60f388875e5b7d9b2b696
sha256:e27e9d7f7f28d67aa9e2d7540bdc2b33254b452ee8e60f388875e5b7d9b2b696: Pulling from library/ubuntu
Digest: sha256:e27e9d7f7f28d67aa9e2d7540bdc2b33254b452ee8e60f388875e5b7d9b2b696
Status: Image is up to date for ubuntu@sha256:e27e9d7f7f28d67aa9e2d7540bdc2b33254b452ee8e60f388875e5b7d9b2b696
Tagging ubuntu@sha256:e27e9d7f7f28d67aa9e2d7540bdc2b33254b452ee8e60f388875e5b7d9b2b696 as ubuntu:latest
```

Read more about [content_trust](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/trust/content_trust/)

Comment: @vathanLal, does validation works? How did you test with invalid docker image?

Comment: I enabled docker content trust then it pulls only trusted images from Docker registry. Before enabling it Docker pulls un-trusted images also. In Docker hub I also checked  Docker Security Scan results of the image I want to pull and I used the image that doesn't have any security vulnerabilities in the scan results..

Answer (score 0):

Enable docker content trust then it pulls only trusted images from Docker registry. That is only signed images are pulled from the registry. Before enabling it Docker pulls un-trusted images also.

```
export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1
```

In Docker hub also check Docker Security Scan results of the image you want to pull and use the image that doesn't have any security vulnerabilities in the scan results. The below link will give more information about it. https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/official_repos/#should-i-use-official-repositories

Answer (score 0):

## ⚠ WARNING

**Docker Content Trust (DCT) is disabled by default**. Even after it's enabled, **it will silently download and dumbly trust any root keys it obtains** (TOFU). Therefore, if you're using Docker on an ephemeral build system that launches fresh on every execution, then **DCT is entirely security theater and will be vulnerable to MITM attacks on every run.**

#### Solution

Unfortunately, the best thing you can do to verify the authenticity of a Docker image is to TOFU the keys a few times by downloading it on a few different computers from a few different places in the world and *hope* that nobody malicious modified the public keys in-transit in all three cases.

It doesn't appear to be documented anywhere, but per [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/238916/how-to-pin-public-root-key-when-downloading-an-image-with-docker-pull-docker-co?noredirect=1&lq=1) it's clear that docker puts its DCT metadata (including root public keys) in the following location:

```
$HOME/.docker/trust/tuf/docker.io/library
```

Inside this `library` dir exists one dir per publisher. For the purposes of this answer, I'll use `debian` as our example publisher.

You can see the list of the `debian` docker images published to Docker Hub here:

- https://hub.docker.com/_/debian/

#### Solution

Let's say we want to download the `stable-slim` image from the `debian` publisher on Docker Hub. In this example, we'll also use a fresh install of Debian 10 as the docker host.

```
##
# first, install docker
## 
root@disp2716:~# apt-get install docker.io
...
root@disp2716:~#

##
# confirm that there is no docker config dir yet
##

root@disp2716:~# ls -lah /root/.docker
ls: cannot access '/root/.docker': No such file or directory
root@disp2716:~# 

##
# add the debian publisher's root DCT key
##

root@disp2716:~# mkdir -p /root/.docker/trust/tuf/docker.io/library/debian/metadata
root@disp2716:~# chown -R root:root /root/.docker
root@disp2716:~# chmod -R 0700 /root/.docker
root@disp2716:~# echo '{"signed":{"_type":"Root","consistent_snapshot":false,"expires":"2025-08-07T20:55:22.677722315-07:00","keys":{"5717dcd81d9fb5b73aa15f2d887a6a0de543829ab9b2d411acce9219c2f8ba3a":{"keytype":"ecdsa","keyval":{"private":null,"public":"MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEsslGF2xHOYztrocb2OsRF2zth16v170QiLAyKdce1nQgOJ34FOk679ClPL9/RNnJukf2JfQXSlVV/qcsvxV2dQ=="}},"575d013f89e3cbbb19e0fb06aa33566c22718318e0c9ffb1ab5cc4291e07bf84":{"keytype":"ecdsa-x509","keyval":{"private":null,"public":"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"}},"728c96ff5e9f48d4e66d5a0c3ecabfdd90bee2b5f9f80b950ed9c668db264a70":{"keytype":"ecdsa","keyval":{"private":null,"public":"MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAENtpBkDJ2oYaAAVdOkP0A6J0XwUkYGuFRk+q8N4WCPu2VnNIuBJkatPCWdEtHfQ9nNYLeanWgG62/UmJnx3E2Yg=="}},"d48327d85f0490827db7c931eedb58d293e1da5fc425ea0cde3e6c13b397ad69":{"keytype":"ecdsa","keyval":{"private":null,"public":"MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEwfs26T/cpjvNTXVJpK7Wv8oDOnNKL78AT3Y1QD356OIAggwPupX2LQjZU6CVzCjm+pkJIO4clu9Q2n540gKuzQ=="}}},"roles":{"root":{"keyids":["575d013f89e3cbbb19e0fb06aa33566c22718318e0c9ffb1ab5cc4291e07bf84"],"threshold":1},"snapshot":{"keyids":["d48327d85f0490827db7c931eedb58d293e1da5fc425ea0cde3e6c13b397ad69"],"threshold":1},"targets":{"keyids":["5717dcd81d9fb5b73aa15f2d887a6a0de543829ab9b2d411acce9219c2f8ba3a"],"threshold":1},"timestamp":{"keyids":["728c96ff5e9f48d4e66d5a0c3ecabfdd90bee2b5f9f80b950ed9c668db264a70"],"threshold":1}},"version":1},"signatures":[{"keyid":"575d013f89e3cbbb19e0fb06aa33566c22718318e0c9ffb1ab5cc4291e07bf84","method":"ecdsa","sig":"3WbX1VXN9E8LRmSG+E4SQlBUNqBNchhwAStWnRWLLyAOoFNBq5xmIgSO3UYYuKyJvL7kbMoONRbn5Vk2p2Wqrg=="}]}' > /root/.docker/trust/tuf/docker.io/library/debian/metadata/root.json
root@disp2716:~# 
root@disp2716:~# chown root:root /root/.docker/trust/tuf/docker.io/library/debian/metadata/root.json
root@disp2716:~# chmod 0600 /root/.docker/trust/tuf/docker.io/library/debian/metadata/root.json
root@disp2716:~# 

##
# pull the docker image with DCT verification
##

root@disp2716:~# export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1
root@disp2716:~# docker pull debian:stable-slim
Pull (1 of 1): debian:stable-slim@sha256:850a7ee21c49c99b0e5e06df21f898a0e64335ae84eb37d6f71abc1bf28f5632
sha256:850a7ee21c49c99b0e5e06df21f898a0e64335ae84eb37d6f71abc1bf28f5632: Pulling from library/debian
6e640006d1cd: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:850a7ee21c49c99b0e5e06df21f898a0e64335ae84eb37d6f71abc1bf28f5632
Status: Downloaded newer image for debian@sha256:850a7ee21c49c99b0e5e06df21f898a0e64335ae84eb37d6f71abc1bf28f5632
Tagging debian@sha256:850a7ee21c49c99b0e5e06df21f898a0e64335ae84eb37d6f71abc1bf28f5632 as debian:stable-slim
root@disp2716:~#
```

#### Proof

While there's [no way to tell `docker` to fail on TOFU](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2752), we can confirm that the above key pinning works by making the public key something else

```
##
# first, move the docker config dir out of the way
## 

mv /root/.docker /root/.docker.bak

##
# add the debian publisher's root DCT key (note I just overwrote the first 8
# characters of the actual key with "INVALID/")
##

root@disp2716:~# mkdir -p /root/.docker/trust/tuf/docker.io/library/debian/metadata
root@disp2716:~# chown -R root:root /root/.docker
root@disp2716:~# chmod -R 0700 /root/.docker
root@disp2716:~# echo '{"signed":{"_type":"Root","consistent_snapshot":false,"expires":"2025-08-07T20:55:22.677722315-07:00","keys":{"5717dcd81d9fb5b73aa15f2d887a6a0de543829ab9b2d411acce9219c2f8ba3a":{"keytype":"ecdsa","keyval":{"private":null,"public":"INVALID/KoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEsslGF2xHOYztrocb2OsRF2zth16v170QiLAyKdce1nQgOJ34FOk679ClPL9/RNnJukf2JfQXSlVV/qcsvxV2dQ=="}},"575d013f89e3cbbb19e0fb06aa33566c22718318e0c9ffb1ab5cc4291e07bf84":{"keytype":"ecdsa-x509","keyval":{"private":null,"public":"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"}},"728c96ff5e9f48d4e66d5a0c3ecabfdd90bee2b5f9f80b950ed9c668db264a70":{"keytype":"ecdsa","keyval":{"private":null,"public":"INVALID/KoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAENtpBkDJ2oYaAAVdOkP0A6J0XwUkYGuFRk+q8N4WCPu2VnNIuBJkatPCWdEtHfQ9nNYLeanWgG62/UmJnx3E2Yg=="}},"d48327d85f0490827db7c931eedb58d293e1da5fc425ea0cde3e6c13b397ad69":{"keytype":"ecdsa","keyval":{"private":null,"public":"INVALID/KoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEwfs26T/cpjvNTXVJpK7Wv8oDOnNKL78AT3Y1QD356OIAggwPupX2LQjZU6CVzCjm+pkJIO4clu9Q2n540gKuzQ=="}}},"roles":{"root":{"keyids":["575d013f89e3cbbb19e0fb06aa33566c22718318e0c9ffb1ab5cc4291e07bf84"],"threshold":1},"snapshot":{"keyids":["d48327d85f0490827db7c931eedb58d293e1da5fc425ea0cde3e6c13b397ad69"],"threshold":1},"targets":{"keyids":["5717dcd81d9fb5b73aa15f2d887a6a0de543829ab9b2d411acce9219c2f8ba3a"],"threshold":1},"timestamp":{"keyids":["728c96ff5e9f48d4e66d5a0c3ecabfdd90bee2b5f9f80b950ed9c668db264a70"],"threshold":1}},"version":1},"signatures":[{"keyid":"575d013f89e3cbbb19e0fb06aa33566c22718318e0c9ffb1ab5cc4291e07bf84","method":"ecdsa","sig":"3WbX1VXN9E8LRmSG+E4SQlBUNqBNchhwAStWnRWLLyAOoFNBq5xmIgSO3UYYuKyJvL7kbMoONRbn5Vk2p2Wqrg=="}]}' > /root/.docker/trust/tuf/docker.io/library/debian/metadata/root.json
root@disp2716:~# 
root@disp2716:~# chown root:root /root/.docker/trust/tuf/docker.io/library/debian/metadata/root.json
root@disp2716:~# chmod 0600 /root/.docker/trust/tuf/docker.io/library/debian/metadata/root.json
root@disp2716:~# 

##
# pull the docker image with DCT verification
##

root@disp2716:~# export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1
root@disp2716:~# docker pull debian:stable-slim
could not validate the path to a trusted root: unable to retrieve valid leaf certificates
root@disp2716:~# 
root@disp2716:~# echo $?
1
root@disp2716:~#
```

Note that docker exits 1 with an error refusing to pull the `debian:stable-slim` docker image from Docker Hub because it cannot trust its signature

```
sudo su -
mkdir -p /root/.docker/trust/tuf/docker.io/library/debian/metadata
chown -R root:root /root/.docker
chmod -R 0700 /root/.docker
echo '{"signed":{"_type":"Root","consistent_snapshot":false,"expires":"2025-08-07T20:55:22.677722315-07:00","keys":{"5717dcd81d9fb5b73aa15f2d887a6a0de543829ab9b2d411acce9219c2f8ba3a":{"keytype":"ecdsa","keyval":{"private":null,"public":"MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEsslGF2xHOYztrocb2OsRF2zth16v170QiLAyKdce1nQgOJ34FOk679ClPL9/RNnJukf2JfQXSlVV/qcsvxV2dQ=="}},"575d013f89e3cbbb19e0fb06aa33566c22718318e0c9ffb1ab5cc4291e07bf84":{"keytype":"ecdsa-x509","keyval":{"private":null,"public":"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"}},"728c96ff5e9f48d4e66d5a0c3ecabfdd90bee2b5f9f80b950ed9c668db264a70":{"keytype":"ecdsa","keyval":{"private":null,"public":"MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAENtpBkDJ2oYaAAVdOkP0A6J0XwUkYGuFRk+q8N4WCPu2VnNIuBJkatPCWdEtHfQ9nNYLeanWgG62/UmJnx3E2Yg=="}},"d48327d85f0490827db7c931eedb58d293e1da5fc425ea0cde3e6c13b397ad69":{"keytype":"ecdsa","keyval":{"private":null,"public":"MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEwfs26T/cpjvNTXVJpK7Wv8oDOnNKL78AT3Y1QD356OIAggwPupX2LQjZU6CVzCjm+pkJIO4clu9Q2n540gKuzQ=="}}},"roles":{"root":{"keyids":["575d013f89e3cbbb19e0fb06aa33566c22718318e0c9ffb1ab5cc4291e07bf84"],"threshold":1},"snapshot":{"keyids":["d48327d85f0490827db7c931eedb58d293e1da5fc425ea0cde3e6c13b397ad69"],"threshold":1},"targets":{"keyids":["5717dcd81d9fb5b73aa15f2d887a6a0de543829ab9b2d411acce9219c2f8ba3a"],"threshold":1},"timestamp":{"keyids":["728c96ff5e9f48d4e66d5a0c3ecabfdd90bee2b5f9f80b950ed9c668db264a70"],"threshold":1}},"version":1},"signatures":[{"keyid":"575d013f89e3cbbb19e0fb06aa33566c22718318e0c9f
fb1ab5cc4291e07bf84","method":"ecdsa","sig":"3WbX1VXN9E8LRmSG+E4SQlBUNqBNchhwAStWnRWLLyAOoFNBq5xmIgSO3UYYuKyJvL7kbMoONRbn5Vk2p2Wqrg=="}]}' > /root/.docker/trust/tuf/docker.io/library/debian/metadata/root.json

export DOCKER_CONTENT_TRUST=1
docker pull debian:stable-slim
```

Answer (score -2):

You can check official images in Docker Hub and with docker search command

```
docker@default:~$ docker search ubuntu
NAME                                                   DESCRIPTION                                     STARS               OFFICIAL            AUTOMATED
ubuntu                                                 Ubuntu is a Debian-based Linux operating s...   7175                [OK]
```

Mode details in [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/official_repos/) and [docker github](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images)

Comment: Thanks.. But how can I confirm whether the image I used in my Dockerfile is not corrupted?? For example

FROM ubuntu:latest in Dockerfile will download a ubuntu:latest base image.

How can I make sure that the base ubuntu image downloaded is not corrupted?? like a checksum verification of official ubuntu images.

Comment: Docker pull image from docker hub, and it gurantee that is not corrupted.
Usually, image that not begin with `username/` is official. you can build an image without prefix and you cannot push it because image name without prefix reserved to official image

Comment: Thanks.. Is there any method to verify the image from docker hub is secure??

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/official_repos/#how-do-i-know-the-official-repositories-are-secure